# What is the analog in Razor notation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, in example of DotNetOpenAuth I have form in aspx:

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=<%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]) %>" method="post" id="openid_form" %>

</form>
```

And what will be analog of it aspx in Razor?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(---???---)) {}
```

--- update---

Thanks for all for suggestions, answer is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { target = "_top", id = "openid_form" })){}
```

Comment: 1. Why use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` over `Url.Encode`?
2. You should clarify whether Authenticate is an MVC action method or not.

Comment: @adamjford, 2. Yes its MVC action, and tagged with MVC tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `BeginForm`; you can still write `<form>` tags in Razor.

`BeginForm` is used when posting to MVC routes.
If that is an MVC action, you can write

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" id="openid_form" %>

</form>
```

There are multiple ways of doing it, though this is the cleanest way that most closely resembles the sample code you posted.